# In Magento 2, Getting an issue with the toggle button where the status does not change when editing the admin grid form

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, grid-layout, toggle

**I'm using toggle button in my admin form and saved successfully but when I am editing admin grid then toggle button status not changed according to status (true or false)**

[image]

[image]

Update:
I have write the code for toggle button this given
path : [XTeam/Slider/view/adminhtml/ui_component/ui_form.xml].

```
<field name="status" formElement="checkbox">
      <settings>
            <label translate="true">Enabled</label>
            <tooltip>
                  <description translate="true">Status for Showing Imgee in Slider.</description>
            </tooltip>
      </settings>
      <formElements>
            <checkbox>
                  <settings>
                        <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                        <valueMap>
                            <map name="false" xsi:type="boolean">false</map>
                            <map name="true" xsi:type="boolean">true</map>
                        </valueMap>
                   </settings>
            </checkbox>
      </formElements>
</field>
```

And this my controller where save and update the form.
path: [XTeam/Slider/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Submit.php]

```
<?php

namespace XTeam\Slider\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Submit extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_dataExample;
    public $resourcemodel;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \XTeam\Slider\Model\Adminhtml\DataExampleFactory  $dataExample,
        \XTeam\Slider\Model\Adminhtml\ResourceModel\DataExample $resourcemodel
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_dataExample = $dataExample;
        $this->resourcemodel = $resourcemodel;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        // print_r($post);
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam("id");
        if ($id) {
            $id = $post['id'];
            $model = $this->_dataExample->create();
            $this->resourcemodel->load($model, $id, 'id');
            $ImageUrl = $post['image'][0]['url'] ?? '';
            $ImagePath = '';
            if ($ImageUrl != '') {
                $ImagePath = explode('media/', $ImageUrl);
                $ImagePath = $ImagePath[1];
            }
            $model->setData('image', $ImagePath);
            $model->setData('title', $post['title']);
            $model->setData('label', $post['label']);
            $model->setData('status', $post['status']);
            $saveData = $this->resourcemodel->save($model);
            if ($saveData) {
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Insert Record Successfully !'));
            }
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('adminslider/index/index');
        } else {
            $model = $this->_dataExample->create();
            $ImageUrl = $post['image'][0]['url'];
            $ImagePath = '';
            if ($ImageUrl != '') {
                $ImagePath = explode('media/', $ImageUrl);
                $ImagePath = $ImagePath[1];
            }
            $model->setTitle($post['title'])
                ->setLabel($post['label'])
                ->setStatus($post['status'])
                ->setImage($ImagePath);
            $saveData = $model->save();
            if ($saveData) {
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Insert Record Successfully !'));
            }
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('adminslider/index/index');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello dear, can you share your code.?

Comment: hello @mohitvamja , please review this code and give me solution.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello dear I am implementing a grid module using the ui component. works for me. so please check the below code.

/var/www/html/project/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/vernor_module_blog_listing.xml

```
<column name="status">
     <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Active</item>
              <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
           </item>
           <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Inactive</item>
              <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
           </item>
        </item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
           <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
           <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
           <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
           <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
        </item>
     </argument>
  </column>
```

/var/www/html/project/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/module_form.xml

```
<field name="status">
     <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
           <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
           <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
           <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
           <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
           <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
              <item name="false" xsi:type="number">0</item>
           </item>
           <item name="valuesForOptions" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="boolean" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
           </item>
           <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
           <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">status</item>
        </item>
     </argument>
  </field>
```

i will share below screen shot.

[image][image]

[image]

[image]

please check code try work you can more information see below link

https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-create-ui-component-grid-and-form/

Comment: thank you brother @mohitvamja. its working for me........

Comment: thank brother most welcome, Do you have any issues at any time? please tell me and I will help with you.

Comment: hello brother @mohitvamja I have one more query , please review this link given below............
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/371718/hide-some-videos-options-showing-on-product-detail-page-magento2

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the Model/DataProvider file - getData() function. Under this you should define the key of your staus attribute.

ex:-

```
    public function getData()
    {
        $generalInformationKeys = ['id', 'name', 'address', 'status', 'position', 'phone', 'store_id' ];
```

Thanks