# hide some videos options showing on product detail page magento2

Tags: magento2.4, magento-admin

**In magneto 2 , I have added a YouTube video in product detail page and i want to hide some options. How to remove.?
I have attached a image....**[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the controls using additional parameters. Please follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) to learn about youtube parameters

```
{youtube embed url }?version=3&autoplay=1&controls=0&loop=0&rel=0
```

Comment: hello @Grazitti_Dev,  thanks for update but this solution is not working in magento2 because  magento is using fotorama library to render videos on product page........